# Existence of a minimal, weakly mixing and Lipschitz selfmap?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, metric-spaces, topological-dynamics, mixing

I am looking for an example of a dynamical system $(M,f)$ such that:

- $M$ is a metric space;
- $f:M \to M$ is Lipschitz;
- $f$ is weakly mixing (that is $f \times f$ is topologically transitive)
- $f$ is minimal (that is every orbit $\{x , f(x) , f^2(x) , \ldots \}$ is dense).

Does there exists one?